# Subset the dataframe such that "nameDest" starting with "M"

Tags: python, filter, dataset, data-cleaning

I want to subset my dataset to only have data relating to the `nameDest` column values starting with 'M'

[image: the data I am working on]

This is the data I am working on. I want all the rows which have `nameDest` as `Mxxxx`

I tried to do it like this:

`merchant = df.loc[df['nameDest'][0:] == 'M']`.

It did not go well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. What I did is that I first created a list by parsing through that col and checking if any value starts with 'M' if it did then I appended it into the list.
Then I used .isin() with .loc to subset the dataframe.

```
merchant = []
for i in df.nameDest:
    if i[0] == 'M':
        merchant.append(i)
print(merchant[:30])

merchants = df.loc[df['nameDest'].isin(merchant)]
merchants.head()
```